# Dynamic addressing I2C slaves; making it plug-and-play

Tags: labview, i2c

I'm controlling a couple of i2c slaves (**PCA9505**) using the I2C module of National Instruments LabVIEW. I need to improve the project so I can add new slaves to the bus without manually adjusting the address of the slaves. (**pins A0 A1 A2 on PCA9505**). As a consequence, hardcoding the addresses is not a option.

Also, PCA has only 3 pins, so I can add max 8 slaves. I need to go for 16.

**How can I give the slaves dynamic addresses?**

**How can I expand to 16 slaves?**

Thanks for your help!

PS: PCA9505 = 40-bit parallel input/output (I/O) port expansion for I2C-bus applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like to use a configuration file to set the parameters needed for an application.  In this case, it would define the addresses for each device you need to talk to.  Arrays also help a lot here for expandability.

As far as extending your I2C bus, you can use something like a PCA9544A I2C mux.  This chip allows for controlling 4 different buses.  You will have to control the mux as part of your addressing of the individual chips.

Answer (score 0):

From a brief read of the [PCA9505 datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9505_9506.pdf) it doesn't look as if there's any way of selecting the device's address other than using those address lines. You are either going to have to multiplex the bus as crossrulz suggests, so that each device is at the same address on a different I2C bus, and add code to control which one you talk to at any one time, or add some hardware that sets the address lines differently for each device.

Will the devices be added to the bus via some sort of connector? If so could you include the address lines in the connector, so that each connector on the master adapter sets a different address for the device that's plugged in to it? Or if you connect devices in a daisy chain, each device could add 1 to the address on its upstream connector and output the new address on its downstream connector?